# Is std::array safely returnable

Tags: c++, stdarray

Is the below sample function safe from the caller's point of view?

```
std::array<T, SIZE> foo() {
    std::array<T, SIZE> bar;
    // Initialization of bar members...
    return bar;
}
```

I am aware that built-in arrays are not safely returnable but I am unsure if `std::array` is safely returnable. If it is, how is this accomplished?

Comment: Just as a small note, `std::array` uses RAII, or else copying, deleting, ... would not be as smooth as it is now :)

Comment: @rici RVO will not take care of the copying. If anything, it will elide the copying...

Comment: "*I am aware that built-in arrays are not safely returnable*" They're not returnable at all.

Comment: @rici I understand that we'll enough, but the question has nothing to do with the fact that there might be an (elided) copy or not, it's about if it is at all possible to return it safely.

Comment: @rubenvb: that's true and the question has a perfectly good answer. So my comment and rakete1111's were both irrelevant. I deleted mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fine. Returning `bar` from `foo()` makes a copy.

`std::array` is a struct that has an array member. When such a struct is copied, the array is also copied. In other words, the rules differ for bare arrays and arrays contained in structs.

Comment: Makes sense, was not able to find the answer by googling and wanted a sanity check, thank you

Answer (score 1):

As @Brian mentioned `std::array` is a struct that has an array member. Something like this:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct my_array {
    T array[N];
};
```

Note that when you copy a `my_array`, its `array` is **deeply copied**. So returning such structs from a function, which makes a copy to a temporary object, would never cause problems. So, with or without presence of [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), it always ensures that there will be no problem.

```
my_array<int, 5> foo = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
my_array<int, 5> bar;

// Copy assignment here
bar = foo;

// Change bar's first element
bar.array[0] = 12;

// Print foo
std::copy(std::begin(foo.array),
          std::end(foo.array),
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
```

Result:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
```

Comment: The question was about why a local container on the stack is safely returned to the caller

Comment: @asimes Ok. I removed irrelevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine but it can potentially be slow.

C++17 introduces guaranteed copy elision, but NRVO is not included.